# SharePoint online set “Structural Navigation: Display only the navigation items below the current site on Quick Launch"

Tags: sharepoint-online, current-navigation

So I'm trying to enable "Structural Navigation: Display only the navigation items below the current site" on all my subsites using pnp provisioning but it can't seem too get it working. I've both tried using  and using properity bag but it wont work...

Anyone have an idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works based on my test(publishing site).

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                AreaNavigationEntity nav = new AreaNavigationEntity();
                nav.CurrentNavigation.ShowSubsites = true;
                nav.CurrentNavigation.ShowPages = true;
                ctx.Web.UpdateNavigationSettings(nav);

            }
```